# Switch branch for different projects in one click

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have different projects in Eclipse linked to them and it's common for me to create a branch for a funcionality that affects all or part of them, is there a way to switch multiple projects to the their branch with the same name?
I see that if you select multiple projects and you right click on them you get this menu:

[image]

but even if they both have a branch with the same name it doesnt appear there.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, just select those repositories in the _Git Repositories_ view and right-click. In the _Git Repositories_ view, you can also create a so-called _Repositories Group_ (via view menu), so you can right-click the group folder. I like the idea that this should also works when selecting projects from different Git repositories. Have you reported this as an enhancement, best with a pull request?

Comment: those are indeed two different projects with different git repositories, no I haven't reported that to Eclipse , but in my experience I have to say they are not very active on new features... So basing on your reply I can assume at the moment it's not possible to archive what I said , right? What would be a use case for Repositories Group ?

Comment: The feature is there, but at a different place in the UI than you asked for: select the repositories in the _Git Repositories_ view and do a right-click. You can create a so-called _Repositories Group_ which is a folder that can be right-clicked, e.g. to switch all repositories that are contained in that group folder to the same named branch. [EGit is very active on new features, except for the last release 6.3](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/New_and_Noteworthy). Everything I reported has been fixed. In open source there is no _they_, there is only _we_.